# In assembly language can you have more than one statement in a textequ?

Tags: assembly

```
sample_thingy textequ <mov,eax 0 add,eax 10>

sample_thingy
call writedec
```

(also what's it called when you do this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Assuming you mean `masm`, I've never actually seen it used this way.

All the stuff I've seen used it as it was intended, as a manifest constant, something like:

```
format_string textequ <[bp+6]>
              :
              mov     ax, format_string   ; becomes: mov ax, [bp+6]
```

For non-constants like entire lines as in your question, I'd probably be using macros rather than manifest constants, something like (it's been a while since I used `masm` so this *may* not be up to date):

```
sample_thingy macro
              mov    eax, 0
              add    eax, 10
              endm
```

Whether the manifest constant method would work in your scenario boils down to three things:

1. Is the statement `mov,eax 0 add,eax 10` valid on a single line? I suspect not.
2. Can you embed newline characters (and possibly tabs) into the manifest constant to force a line break and formatting? I have no idea.
3. What happened when you tried it? :-)

Comment: Thank you I tried the things you mentioned and tried throwing commas in and stuff, but it doesn't seem like you can do this!